# use mysql result in php string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to do a simple login script with php, my issue is the part that takes the password of the user out of the database to compare it with what has been entered.

Right now my code does not compare, but echo the password so i can see its working before going further, yet... i cannot get the password, my SQL query works fine, tried it in phpmyadmin. but the echo does not show anything! i dont get it.

```
$account = $_POST['account']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else { 
$query = "SELECT password FROM account WHERE login = '$account'";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
$pass = $row['password'];
echo "$pass";
}
```

Comment: You're missing a line between `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` and `$pass = $row['password'];`.  Hint: it's how `$row` becomes set.  P.S. This code is unsafe.  You should switch to MySQLi (or PDO) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to actually FETCH your query's results:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // you forgot this
```

And beyond that, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).